# No header files generated - when cocoapods packaging a framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I try to package a static library with cocoapods . but I only get a file named "libLTVoiceAssistant.a"

The project was generated via `pod lib create LTVoiceAssistant` ,and then ,I moved my codes and some frameworks into it . And `pod lib lint LTVoiceAssistant.podspec` passed ... well , you guys must know that because I've packaged a static library.
here is my spec file content:

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|

     s.version          = '0.1.3'

     s.source           = { :git => '/Users/kenny/Documents/LTVoiceAssistant', :tag => s.version.to_s }


     s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

    s.requires_arc = true
    s.resource = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/Cells/*.xib'
    s.source_files = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/**/*.{c,h,hh,m,mm,cpp,a}'

   s.resource_bundles = {
      'LTVoiceAssistantBundle' => ['LTVoiceAssistant/Assets/LTVoiceAssistantBundle/**/*']
     }
   s.public_header_files = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/PublicHeader/*.h'
   s.ios.vendored_libraries = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/libBDVoiceRecognitionClient.a',
                         'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/libBDSSpeechSynthesizer.a'

   s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/*.framework'

   s.frameworks = 'Foundation','UIKit','JavaScriptCore','CoreText','CoreFoundation',
              'CoreGraphics','GLKit','QuartzCore','OpenGLES','CoreLocation','CFNetwork',
              'Security','CoreTelephony','SystemConfiguration','AVFoundation','AudioToolbox'

    s.libraries = 'iconv.2.4.0','z.1.2.5','stdc++.6.0.9','c++','z.1'
    s.preserve_paths = 'LTVoiceAssistant/Classes/*.framework'

    s.dependency 'Aspects'
    s.dependency 'Objection', '1.6.1'
    s.dependency 'ReactiveCocoa','2.5'
    s.dependency 'MJExtension'
    s.dependency 'Masonry'
    s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
    s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack','3.0'
    s.dependency 'INTULocationManager'
   end
```

And I used `pod package LTVoiceAssistant.podspec --library --force` command to package. Was I missed something ?

My project tree:
[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnwkH.jpg)
FYI : I also try to generage framework type ,use `pod package LTVoiceAssistant.podspec  --force` ,well ,header files appeared .
and then ,I new a test project ,and try to import header, well, error comes ...
[not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKh2h.jpg)

Comment: Did you try #import < LTVoiceAssistant /LTVoiceAssistant .h>